# open new page from nav drawer xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, navigation-drawer, xamarin.forms, content-pages

I'm working on a Xamarin Forms App. This App has a ContentPage as MainPage, this ContenPage has 2 buttons. One of them, after being clicked, shows a new Page (I'm using `App.Current.MainPage = page;`) and this new page has a Nav Drawer.

The Nav Drawer shows perfectly, and all its pages work fine, but what I want to do is open a new page (lets call it "events") from one of this nav drawer pages. Every time a Nav Drawer Item is clicked, I use the code above:

```
if (menu == null)
   return;
Page displayPage = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(menu.TargetType); //the error shows here after trying to open my "events" page
Detail = new NavigationPage (displayPage);
menuPage.Menu.SelectedItem = null;
IsPresented = false;
```

But then, on my Nav Drawer Page, I'm trying to open my "events" page, but I don't know how to open it. I tried to use Navigation.PushAsyng(page) or App.Current.MainPage = page; but none of those work. Everytime I try to open it, this Unhandled Exception shows

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation

I use this reference for creating my nav drawer https://syntaxismyui.com/xamarin-forms-masterdetail-page-navigation-recipe/
So, does someone know how to solve this problem and open my "events" page? I've been trying to do this for a long time without any results.

Thanks!

Comment: if you try hardcoding "Page displayPage = new EventsPage()" (whatever the name of your events page is) does it work?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't know where I am supossed to write that... Could you please help me with that?

Comment: replace the line where you create displayPage with Activator - if it still breaks that means something is wrong with your Events page.  If it works, then the problem is more likely related to Activator/reflection.

Comment: I can't do that, because I want to make an instance of the item selected from my Nav Drawer! There is an example of that on the link I included. Anyway, If I replace that line with the code you gave me, it shows a compiling error!

Comment: I was trying to help you determine what is causing the error - Activator or something in your Events page.  My suggestion was not a permanent code change.

Comment: Alternately, you can look at the InnerException property of the exception that is thrown to see if that tells you the root cause.

Comment: Okey, I'll do that. Thanks Jason :)

Comment: Jason, I've solved my problem... It was something stupid actually. The exception was showing because I had a button onClick-event creation before I was initializing the button itself... But thanks anyway !